# Clicking anchor unexpectedly calls alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that retrieves users from a server (ajax) and I use some `<a>` tags to display it, and when you click on an `<a>` tag with a user, it's supposed to add it to an array `in_group`. The first one works, the second one goes to the `alert()` function AND also adds the user to the array, which confuses me. The remove button doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong? I want the user to be added to the `in_group` array only if doesn't exist, and to be deleted when the button is pressed.

```
var in_group = [];

$("#students-body").on('click', 'a', function() {
    var modal = $("#manageGroupMembers");

    var student_id = $(this).attr('student-id');
    var student_name = $(this).html();
    var student = {
        id: student_id,
        name: student_name
    };


    console.log(in_group.length);

    if (in_group.length > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < in_group.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(in_group[i].id);
            if (in_group[i].id === student_id)
            {
                alert('in grp');
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                in_group.push(student);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        in_group.push(student);
    }


    RefreshGroup();
    //modal.modal('hide');
});

function RefreshGroup()
{
    var students_group = $("#students-group");
    var html = "";

    if (in_group.length > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < in_group.length; i++)
        {
            html += "<span>"+in_group[i].name+"</span>";
            html += "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='event.preventDefault();RemoveFromGroup("+i+")'>x</button>";
        }

        students_group.append(html);
    }
}

function RemoveFromGroup(index) {
    in_group.splice(index, 1);
    RefreshGroup();
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="group_members">Members</label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block;" onclick="event.preventDefault()" id="add-student-btn">Add Member</button>
    <div id="students-group"></div>
</div>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="manageGroupMembers" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Member to Group</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="students-body"></div>
                <div id="pagination-students"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your `HTML` codes as well.

Comment: I edited my question to have html as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are inserting the `id` in a for loop. Change your code:

```
...your code before this....
var student_id = $(this).attr('student-id');
var student_name = $(this).html();
var student = {
    id: student_id,
    name: student_name
};

var index = in_group.findIndex(function(std) {
  return std.id == student.id;
});

if(index === -1) {
  in_group.push(student);
} else {
  alert('student was already in array')
}
```

This way, you check if the student is inside the array. If not (-1) you insert it. Else you alert

Answer (score 0):

In this section of your code, you’re looping the `in_group` array to find a student entry with a specific ID.

```
if (in_group.length > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < in_group.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(in_group[i].id);
        if (in_group[i].id === student_id)
        {
            alert('in grp');
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            in_group.push(student);
        }
    }

}
else
{
    in_group.push(student);
}

RefreshGroup();
```

If you find it, you `alert` it, *and then you stop the loop and the entire function*. If you *don’t* find it, you push it, but **you don’t break the loop**. You keep looping, the check `in_group[i].id === student_id` is re-executed and the `alert` is executed as well.

You could add a `return;` after calling `RefreshGroup`, however, why not get rid of the loops and make things easier?

```
let isInGroup = in_group.find(studentEntry => studentEntry.id === student_id);

if(isInGroup){
  alert("in grp");
}
else{
  in_group.push(student);
  RefreshGroup();
}
```

This will replace the above section completely and it will work.

---

As to why the removal doesn’t work:

1. `event` isn’t defined. It’ll likely produce a `ReferenceError`. (Same problem for your other `<button>`.)
2. Instead of inline event attributes, look into event delegation and standard event listeners (jQuery has the `click` method—use it!)
3. Look into `data-` attributes or jQuery’s `data` to hold the value of the index.

Event delegation could look like this:

```
var students_group = $("#students-group");
students_group.on("click", "button", function(e){
  RemoveFromGroup($(this).attr("data-index"));
});
```

And then, when generating the HTML:

```
html += "<button class='btn btn-danger' data-index='" + i + "'>x</button>";
```

---

I’d also recommend reading about [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods, particularly the iteration methods.